# WorkflowCreationEndpoint ResumeBookmark with a filled response

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I've spend days trying to find a solution the problem i'm going to try to describe, i've googled alot and even looked at the .NET 4 reference source for SendReply and InternalSendReply activity. But until now i'm stuck.

To make the life of our end customers simpler i want to replace the Receive and SendReply activities with custom activites and use bookmarks instead.

I'm implementing a central webservice which can route to a correct workflow instance, that workflow modifies the bookmark value and finaly it creates a new bookmark while returning the modified bookmark value. It's rather complex already with a WorkflowServiceHostFactory which adds Behaviours and Attach a DataContractResolver to the endpoint.

The endpoint is derived from WorkflowHostingEndpoint which resolves a bookmark created in a custom activity (instead of a receive). And i want another activity instead of a sendreply. Those 2 should correlate and the custom sendreply does send a response on the open channel through the endpoint while creating a new bookmark.

The problem is that i didn't find a way yet to access the endpoint responseContext from within my custom send activity. On the other side, at the workflowcreating endpoint side, it seems that i'm **not able to be notified whenever the workflow becomes Idle** and as well i don't seem to be able to access the WorkflowExtensions from the host. **i'm missing something?**

A possible solution i've in mind might be not using a WorkflowServiceHost, but then i loose alot of AppFabric functionaly.

The workflowapplication in platform update 1 has some extension methods called RunEpisode with an overload Func called idleEventCallback. There it's possible to hook into the OnIdle and get a workflowextension to get the object to send back as response.

Comment: I forgot to mention each "episode" will have a short lifetime, it's in fact build on top of the new WF statemachine it trigger a transition and the action modifies a value to be returned when the next state is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, i ended up in a workaround using the servicebroker functionality of sql server. The SqlDependency class where the workflow listens for the event to be fired whenever the workflow reach the activity that creates a new bookmark in another state.